# Why is const required for 'operator>' but not for 'operator<'?

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading

Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
    int key;
    std::string stringValue;

    MyStruct(int k, const std::string& s) : key(k), stringValue(s) {}

    bool operator < (const MyStruct& other) {
        return (key < other.key);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector < MyStruct > vec;

    vec.push_back(MyStruct(2, "is"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(1, "this"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(4, "test"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(3, "a"));

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (const MyStruct& a : vec) {
        cout << a.key << ": " << a.stringValue << endl;
    }
}
```

It compiles fine and gives the output one would expect. But if I try to sort the structures in descending order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
    int key;
    std::string stringValue;

    MyStruct(int k, const std::string& s) : key(k), stringValue(s) {}

    bool operator > (const MyStruct& other) {
        return (key > other.key);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::vector < MyStruct > vec;

    vec.push_back(MyStruct(2, "is"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(1, "this"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(4, "test"));
    vec.push_back(MyStruct(3, "a"));

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), greater<MyStruct>());

    for (const MyStruct& a : vec) {
        cout << a.key << ": " << a.stringValue << endl;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error. [Here is the full message](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Rockstar5645/Le4A48):

> /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::greater<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = MyStruct]':
>   /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:376:20: error: no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'const MyStruct' and 'const MyStruct')
>          { return __x > __y; }

It seems to be because this function right here doesn't have a `const` qualifier:

```
bool operator > (const MyStruct& other) {
        return (key > other.key);
}
```

If I add it,

```
bool operator > (const MyStruct& other) const {
        return (key > other.key);
}
```

Then everything is fine again. Why is this so? I'm not too familiar with operator overloading, so I've just put it in memory that we need to add the `const` but it's still weird why it works for `operator<` without the `const`.

Comment: Which compiler have you used? What is version of that?

Comment: gcc 7.2.0 https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++

Comment: @Rockstart5645 what is of this relevance here?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You get different behaviors because you are in fact calling two different (overloaded) [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) functions.

In the first case you call the two parameter `std::sort`, which uses `operator<` directly. Since the iterators to your vector elements produce non-const references, it can apply `operator<` just fine.

In the second case, you are using the three parameter version of `std::sort`. The one that accepts a functor. You pass `std::greater`. And that functor has an `operator()` declared as follows:

```
constexpr bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

Note the const references. It binds the elements it needs to compare to const references. So your own `operator>` must be const correct as well.

If you were to call `std::sort` with [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), your `operator<` will produce the same error, because it's not const-correct.

Comment: Nitpicking: except `std::less<void>`.

Answer (score 27):

Use of `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())` depends only on the `operator<` function. It does not require that the function be able to work with `const` objects.

`std::greater`, on the other hand, requires the function be able to work with `const` objects.

You will see a similar problem if you use `std::less`, such as `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::less<MyStruct>())`.

---

Having said that, there is no reason for the `operator<` function and the `operator>` function to be non-`const` member functions. Any member function that does not modify member data should be made a `const` member function.